# Como inserir vários endereços de e-mails dentro de uma variável apenas, no SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, declaração-de-variável

Por exemplo:

Se ao invés de eu digitar apenas um endereço de e-mail na variável abaixo, eu digitasse 30 endereços de e-mails, o que eu teria que alterar na minha query abaixo?

```
DECLARE @email as NVARCHAR
SET @email = 'joaquim@padaria.com'
 
Select * FROM Padarias WHERE email = @email
```

Comment: Não creio que seja uma boa ideia trabalhar com atributos multi-valorados. Repense sua estratégia.

Comment: Pelo que entendi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160456/sql-server-procedure-declare-a-list

Comment: Muito obrigado Motta, a solução apresentada neste link serve para o meu caso! Um forte agraço.

Answer (score 0):

Caso você esteja usando a partir da versão 2016 em diante do SQL Server, basta utilizar a função nativa `string_split`. Veja a seguir:

```
DECLARE @email as NVARCHAR(max)
SET @email = 'joaquim@padaria.com,manuel@padaria.com,pedro@padaria.com,maria@padaria.comandre@padaria.com'--e-mails de exemplo

Select * 
FROM Padarias 
WHERE email in(select value
                from string_split(@email, ',')--> O delimitador deve ser o mesmo usado para separar os e-mails inseridos na variável
                )
```